# Custom CursorAdaptor is showing nothing

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I'm trying to do a list getting the data from y sqlite db using a custom CursorAdaptor to show an image an some data to the right, but so far all I got was a blank screen or a spinning loading circle without a result.

Here is my fragment activity:

```
public class FragMvp extends SherlockListFragment {

    private DataBaseManager dataBase;
    private MyCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // creates and open the database so we can use it
        dataBase = DataBaseManager.instance();

        String query = "SELECT mo._id,mo.sprite,mo.iName FROM Mobs AS mo WHERE mo.MobType = 2 ORDER BY mo.iName ASC;";

        Cursor cursor = dataBase.select(query);

        if (cursor != null) {
            mAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), cursor, false);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something with the data
    }
}
```

The query is working perfectly on my database manager and if I use an ArrayAdapter, it works and shows data. So I guess that the problem is not database related.

Then, here is the CursorAdapter:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String mobSprite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sprite"));
        String mobName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("iName"));
        int lvl = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("LVL"));
        String hp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("HP"));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobSprite);
        TextView mobNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobName);
        TextView levelView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvl);
        TextView hpView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hp);

        int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mobSprite, "drawble", context.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(resID);
        mobNameView.setText(mobName);
        levelView.setText(lvl);
        hpView.setText(hp);
    }
}
```

And the XML just in case. It's not finished yet, but first I want to see some results and see how they look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mobSprite"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@+id/mobName"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lvlString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/lvl"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lvl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lvlString"
                android:text="@+id/lvl"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hpString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/hp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hpString"
                android:text="@+id/hp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know where is the problem, I've look for countless of tutorials and it's always the same. Do the CursorAdapter, pass it the cursor and context and set the listAdapter... but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
Cursor cursor = dataBase.select(query);
if (cursor != null) {
    mAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), cursor, false);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    cursor.close(); <========
}
```

You are closing the cursor prematurely. If you close it here, the Adapter will have zero results. The CursorAdapter will take care of closing the cursor when it is done or when you change the cursor to a new one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh dear... Now is crashing for another reason, but at least I'm not stuck any more! Thank you very much! Now let's go fix the new problems... :D